# Trying to embed date_add comparison in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, datetime, comparison

Should be fairly self-explanatory; any idea why I can't do:

```
select user_id from my_table where created_at<date_add(min(created_at), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

I'm trying to only return rows that have been created within a minute of the earliest timestamp. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use HAVING instead of WHERE when dealing with aggregate functions... Still, your query will be a bit more complex, I guess:

```
SELECT user_id, 
       created_at, (
           SELECT DATE_ADD(MIN(created_at), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
           FROM my_table
       ) AS earliest
  FROM my_table t1
HAVING created_at < earliest;
```

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe461/21/0) to play with. )

Comment: oddly enough, I tried that, and I get an unknown column (created_at) error 1054... even when I try and do my_table.created_at.

Comment: do I need some kind of join here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM my_table
WHERE created_at < DATE_ADD((SELECT MIN(created_at) FROM my_table), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id FROM my_table
WHERE created_id <
(
   SELECT (min_dt + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) mindt FROM 
   (SELECT MIN(created_id) min_dt FROM my_table) A
);
```